# what is the physical path that Jasperserver store its resources?

Tags: jasperserver

I need to know the Physical location Jasperserver use to store the uploaded resources from IReport.

Answer (score 5):

It stores all assets in the database including any binary files you upload. Nothing is stored in the filesystem directly.