# Using subreport in web application

Tags: web-applications, jasper-reports, subreport

I am generating my report on server side (not *JasperReports Server* it is different). When I add subreport server can't find path to subreport. My main report in "reports" directory and I created new directory in "reports" which is "/subreports", so the path to subreport is "reports/subreports/report_1". In XML file I set this path

```xml
 <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/subreports/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
```

and on path property of subreport I set $P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport"

what would be the problem with this?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it. I am using a Spring REST web app. I created a folder inside WEB-INF named **reports**. Here I have my main report ***not compiled***, say, **report_main.jrxml** and my subreport ***compiled***, say, **subreport.jasper**, then, inside *report_main*, I set the property *Subreport Expression* of the subreport object to ***$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport.jasper"***.

$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} is an input variable to the main report, of type string, that will contain the physical path where the subreport will be located. I get this physical path at runtime on my web app and I pass it to the jasper compiler like this.

```
String fullPath = servletContext.getRealPath("WEB-INF/reports");
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", fullPath );

JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fileName);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. Also note that you can get the ServletContext into your Spring Controller using: 

@Autowired private ServletContext servletContext;

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the report is in the right folder defined by the parameter SUBREPORT_DIR; you would need to use the double quote + extension:

```xml
$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"MySubreport.jrxml"
```

The XML of calling report should look like this:

```xml
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"MySubreport.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
```

Also make sure the report name & resource ID identical including the extension.

Furthermore, keep in mind that jasperserver keeps the report in its own DB. So I doubt it would work with remote links: See also this questions:

[what is the physical path that Jasperserver store its resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374905/what-is-the-physical-path-that-jasperserver-store-its-resources)

Comment: I tried what you wrote. But now I am getting - "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :
Source text : $P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"report.jasper" error.

Comment: yes, I tried with it. May be issue is "$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}" and Subreport class types. Because by default they are String, should I change them. If I should, but must be class type?

Comment: Check if the parameter contains the right value, could you also double check the XML definition?

Comment: My report is being generated in serverside, so there is no path problem right now. Because new error is - "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from InputStream".  I think thisis compiling issue. May be server can not compile subreport.

Comment: The last problem is - "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : ./subreports/report.jasper". My server uses Linux as operation system. My file directory is in this style "/reports/main_report" and "/reports/subreport/subreport_1" so my path expression would be correct. Main issue is not obvious now.

Comment: How did you create the folder and subreport?

Comment: I created report and subreport in dropbox, and I have got portal, for running the report+subreport I call them from that portal (from browser) and it generates pdf. So, the report+subreport are being generated in server side.